# How do I get this turtle problem to properly increment?

Tags: python, for-loop, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Complete beginner to coding and Python here, so bear with me. I'm trying to solve this question:

A sprite is a simple spider shaped thing with n legs coming out from a center point. The angle between each leg is 360 / n degrees.

I'm having trouble with my move variable. I can get it to work for a single value, but I want it to work for any value input by the user.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
sprite = turtle.Turtle()

str_legs = input("How many legs does the sprite have?")
print(int(str_legs))

move = (360/int(str_legs)) 
for s in range (int(str_legs)): 
    sprite.fd(100)
    sprite.home()
    sprite.right(move)    
    move = ?

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble with my move variable." - in your own words, **what is the intended purpose** of this variable? It seems like you are trying to figure out how to change it each time through the loop. But I do not understand why you think it should change at all - nor do I understand what result you expect from the code, or your general idea about how to get that result. Please start by carefully thinking through the logic. (For example, exactly what happens when you call `sprite.home`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `home()` always puts the turtle in the same heading and position (facing right). Instead, try to figure out how to return home but preserve the heading the turtle had when it started the current leg.

```py
import turtle

legs = 8
leg_size = 100
degrees_per_turn = 360 / legs

sprite = turtle.Turtle()

for _ in range(legs):
    sprite.forward(leg_size)
    sprite.backward(leg_size)
    sprite.right(degrees_per_turn)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

If you want to stick with `home()`, you can turn one turn amount times the number of turns completed so far:

```py
# ...

for i in range(legs):
    sprite.forward(leg_size)
    sprite.home()
    sprite.right(degrees_per_turn * (i + 1))

# ...
```

That said, I think the top version is cleaner, and take note because it's a common pattern in turtle applications. In general, the idea is to use *relative* functions rather than *absolute* functions. `forward()`, `backward()` and `right()` are examples of relative functions (they take the current position or heading into consideration), while `home()`, `setposition()` and `setheading()` are absolute functions (they disregard the current position or heading). It's like the difference between `+=` (relative) and `=` (absolute) when working with integers.

Although I didn't bother doing so here, typically, you'll want to `penup()` when heading back to home and `pendown()` again once you've repositioned the turtle.

As a final side note, avoid `input()` until everything is totally working otherwise. It's tedious to have to type a number in every time you run the code during development, and it makes it harder for others to reproduce bugs if they're not sure what to type in if you post the code as a question.

Comment: Yep, changing home to backward got it working perfectly. Thanks for your help and the additional advice.